# Conditional parametrization of test in pytest

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, pytest

I want to create tests with dependencies.
As an example, let's say that I want to test sending email process in some application and correctness of received email on mailbox.
**I don't want to test correctness of received email if the test for sending email failed.** So I came up with an idea to create something like this:

```py
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    SENT_EMAILS = []

    def test_sending_email_case_1(self):
        message = send_message()
        self.SENT_EMAILS.append(message)
    
    def test_sending_email_case_2(self):
        message = send_message()
        self.SENT_EMAILS.append(message)

    @parameterized.expand(SENT_EMAILS, skip_on_empty=True)
    def test_email_content_on_mailbox(self, email):
        pass
```

I had set up pytest to run tests in order. For parametrization I use library called [parameterized](https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/). But unfortunately it leads to this error, when SENT_EMAILS is empty:

```
            with outcome.testPartExecutor(self):
                self.setUp()
            if outcome.success:
                outcome.expecting_failure = expecting_failure
                with outcome.testPartExecutor(self, isTest=True):
>                   testMethod()
E                   TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

/usr/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py:628: TypeError
```

I can't make it work and i'm not sure is it even correct way. Am I missing something? Or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You can use [pytest-dependency](https://github.com/RKrahl/pytest-dependency) to mark tests as dependent on other tests - they will be skipped if the tests they depend on are failed or skipped.

Comment: Apart from that, it would be better to be able to have independent tests, for example by mocking sending mails while testing receiving mails.

Comment: Those tests are not unit tests. It supposed to automate manual testers work and to see how everything is working together. I think I can say that those are integration tests. That's why I didn't want to mock anything to keep it closest to the behavior of human and it couldn't be independent. Do you think that's fine? btw. I will try pytest-dependency, but I need to figure out how to add new items to SENT_EMAILS, because adding it in previous tests is not working (I think that's because passing argument to parameterized.expand is done by value, not reference). Prob, I will try to use generator

Comment: I think this is ok. I haven't used `parametrized` (`@pytest.mark.parametrize` has been sufficient so far), so I'm not sure about that behavior.